# How to get the index of an element in a tuple via address?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

For example:

```
std::tuple<int, double> t;
void* p = &std::get<1>(t);
```

Now I want to get p's index by some function like

```
template<typename... Ts>
size_t index(void* p, std::tuple<Ts...> const& t)
{
   ...
}
```

Sure the result is 1 for this example. I am interested in how to implement the function to get the index when p is obtained by ways other than the explicit index.

Comment: Does it matter which one if multiple are at the same place?

Comment: No. But I think it won't happen. Please give me an example if so.

Comment: Why?  This seems pretty strange.

Comment: Do you have distinct types in your tuple? Or do you have multiple elements with the same type?

Comment: @MarcoA.: `std::tuple<int, double>`; it's right there in the question.

Comment: Sure but that might be a "snippet".. I've seen too many "*this is just an example*" code

Comment: This is not possible in general, since tuple element types which are empty need not to have unique addresses: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/332ab0e36a83d65e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something you do not need in C++14, a mini indexes library:

```
template<unsigned...>struct indexes{using type=indexes;};
template<unsigned Cnt,unsigned...Is>
struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Cnt-1,Cnt-1,Is...>{};
template<unsigned...Is>
struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};
template<unsigned Cnt>
using make_indexes_t=typename make_indexes<Cnt>::type;
```

Function that does actual work.  Creates an array pointers-to-elements.  Then searches for `p`.  The `nullptr` and `-1` make it work for empty tuples.

```
template<unsigned...Is,class Tuple>
unsigned index_of(indexes<Is...>,void const* p, Tuple const&t){
  void const* r[]={ nullptr, &std::get<Is>(t)... };
  auto it = std::find( std::begin(r), std::end(r), p );
  if (it==std::end(r))
    return -1;
  else
    return (it-std::begin(r))-1;
}
```

you can put that in a `details` namespace.

The final function:

```
template<class...Ts>
unsigned index_of( void const*p, std::tuple<Ts...> const& t ){
  return index_of( make_indexes_t<sizeof...(Ts)>{}, p, t );
}
```

return `unsigned(-1)` on failure.

Comment: Is that truly the `Max`? You only ever add `Max-1` to the template parameter list, as far as I can see..

Comment: @dyp creates indexes from the half open interval 0 to max.

Comment: Yes, so `max` isn't the maximum of that sequence :( -- anyway, shouldn't that be a `max_element`?

Comment: @dyp: Yakk uses unsigned type, so -1 becomes the greatest one

Comment: @Yakk: any specific purpose I don't see for using `(index_to_address<Is>{}(t)==p?Is:-1)...` instead of simple `(&std::get<Is>(t)==p?Is:-1)...` ?

Comment: @piotrs. because I wrote it backward: my first implememtation involved iterating directly over the tuple.  That requres more boilerplate, so I boiled down.  But remnants remain.

Comment: @dyp rewritten to be even more brief.  Could probably het better optimization by subtracting `&t` from everything and working in offsets (as said offsets are constants, except for `p`).

Comment: `void const* r[]={ p, &std::get<Is>(t)... }; auto const it = find(rbegin(r), rend(r), p); return (it.base() - r) - 1;` but that's much uglier.

Answer (score 2):

Logarithmic complexity in terms of comparisons is possible - under the assumption that adresses of consecutive elements are decreasing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

// minimalistic index-list implementation

template <std::size_t...> struct index_list {using type = index_list;};

template <typename, typename> struct concat;
template <std::size_t... i, std::size_t... j>
struct concat<index_list<i...>, index_list<j...>> : index_list<i..., j...> {};

// (Inefficient) linear recursive definition of make_indices:
template <std::size_t N> struct make_indices :
    concat<typename make_indices<N-1>::type, index_list<N-1>> {};
template <> struct make_indices<0> : index_list<> {};
template <> struct make_indices<1> : index_list<0> {};

// </>

template <typename T, typename = typename make_indices<std::tuple_size<T>::value>::type> struct offsets;

template <typename... T, std::size_t... indices>
struct offsets<std::tuple<T...>, index_list<indices...>>
{
    static std::size_t index_of(void* p, std::tuple<T...> const& t)
    {
        static const std::tuple<T...> tuple;

        static const std::ptrdiff_t array[]
        {
            reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&std::get<indices>(tuple)) - reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&tuple)...
        };

        auto offset_p_t = static_cast<char const*>(p) - reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&t);

        auto iter = std::lower_bound( std::begin(array), std::end(array), offset_p_t, std::greater<>() );

        if (iter == std::end(array)
         || *iter != offset_p_t)
            return -1;

        return iter - std::begin(array);
    }
};


template <typename... T>
std::size_t index_of(void* p, std::tuple<T...> const& t) {return offsets<std::tuple<T...>>::index_of(p, t);}

int main ()
{
    std::tuple<int, double, std::string> t;
    void* p = &std::get<2>(t);

    std::cout << index_of(p, t);
}
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83a6f415cb1931e7)**.

Comment: Note that for tuples with less tham dozens of elements, a simpler linear search will probably beat a more complex logarithmic.  I like the static offset array trick, constexpr without constexpr.  Note your code fail to compile on empty tuples: you can add a stub to the array, or just specialize it.

Comment: @Yakk Thanks. I didn't really think about the empty tuple case. And you're correct -- for smaller tuples a linear search does a better job, i just felt this was complementary. Btw: I don't really think that the array is filled at compile time since `__builtin_constant_p` returns `false`.

Comment: I would not be surprised.  Think of the math the compiler will do: the optimizer would have to work to avoid makimg it compile time, or screw up.

Comment: @Yakk I measured both variants and yours is indeed a lot faster (~15%). I'll try to write an own binary search algo and check again.

Comment: Neither are the addresses guaranteed to be increasing/decreasing, nor are they guaranteed to be unique: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02fbe2d829bf6a78

Comment: @dyp I know about the EBO in `std::tuple`. I just felt it was too much work to consider that here. And i said that under the *assumption* that they are decreasing the code works, I didn't imply that that is the case on all common implementations.

Comment: Yes, it's fine under that assumption. My intention is to show that there are real examples that violate that assumption. I.e., it's not just a language-lawyer problem. Also consider: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e574122fb627ce02 the addresses can be increasing or decreasing, so this is quite nonportable.