# Array compile-time generated?

Tags: c++

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26204533/1938163) (it is not strictly necessary to read the whole question + answer) some code produces a compile-time array like:

```
template<unsigned...Is,class Tuple>
unsigned index_of(indexes<Is...>,void const* p, Tuple const&t){
  void const* r[]={ nullptr, &std::get<Is>(t)... }; // <-- this is the array I'm referring to
  auto it = std::find( std::begin(r), std::end(r), p );
  if (it==std::end(r))
    return -1;
  else
    return (it-std::begin(r))-1;
}
```

My question is: is that array entirely compile-time generated with the addresses of each element of a tuple? Is that the compile-time advantage? Or is the array runtime-generated (in that case, where's the compile-time advantage at all?)

---

Rephrased: why is the complex templated code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26204533/1938163) necessary at all instead of a simple runtime function which iterates with a for loop over all the elements of the tuple and compares the pointers? What's the gain in all that?? Something regarding the array creation? I don't really see it and I can't believe all that work was done for nothing or just to brag around "*I can mess stuff up with templates, take a look*"

Comment: What does "generated" mean?

Comment: What a weird-ass algorithm. What's with the `unsigned` result but returning -1? And the pointless first `nullptr` argument, and the `- 1` offset in the end?

Comment: @KerrekSB kinda agree, but I didn't write it :] Anyway I'm interested in knowing if the addresses are statically determined at compile-time

Comment: The addresses can obviously not statically determined if the tuple parameter is only supplied dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

No, since the tuple address is not known at compile-time. The only thing thats known at compile time is the size of the array, since its extracted from the size of the tuple (Via pack expansion).

Thats a weird algorithm thats only doing type erasure via `void*` to be able to store tuple elements on an array and then do something on them via standard algorithms.

This has much more sense (Indices trick ommitted to be more clear):

```
template<typename Tuple , typename T>
bool find_in_tuple( const Tuple& t , const T& e )
{
    bool result[] = { (std::get<Indices>( t ) == e)... };

    return std::any_of(std::begin(result) , std::end(result) , [](bool b){ return b; } );
}
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1939b69735cb030) is a running example.

For the `index_of` feature, you can add a counter to the closure when doing `any_of()`, or do something more complicated like this:

```
template<typename Tuple , typename T>
std::index_of index_of( const Tuple& t , const T& e )
{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    std::tuple<bool,std::size_t> result[] = { std::make_tuple(Indices,std::get<Indices>( t ) == e)... };

    bool exists = std::any_of(std::begin(result) , std::end(result) , [&](const std::pair<std::size_t,bool>& p){ index = p.first; return p.second; } );

    if(exists)
        return index;
    else
        throw std::bad_argument{};
}
```

Comment: Thank, just one more question: **why all that template boilerplate if we gain nothing instead of a normal runtime "foreach element check_address()" function??**

Comment: @user3834459 I'm not sure, but I'm agree with you: If you type erased the tuple via `void*` then the pack trick has no sense, just do a loop. On the other hand, computing the addresses of tuple elements is not an easy task, so that could be the reason. What has no sense at all is to do what the author is doing to achieve something thats perfectly done without poorly efficient type erasure at all.

Comment: I believe he did it since the question asked for it specifically. Anyway I would have expected a massive performance gain from all that stuff since complexity increased substantially. If there's small or no point in all that.. well... he might also have written that in malbolge programming language as well.